# DescribePixelFormat "requires a newer version of Windows"

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, directx

I ran into some strange behavior while upgrading a compiler from VS 2010 Ultimate to VS 2013 Professional.  The operating system is Windows 7 Professional.

Using `GetLastError()`, I tracked the problem down to a `DescribePixelFormat(...)` call.  Before it, there is no error.  Immediately after it, I get error 1150 (which is apparently "The specified program requires a newer version of Windows.").

Edit: The code looks like this:

```
HWND window = CreateWindowEx(...);
HDC device_context = GetDC(window);

DWORD error_before = GetLastError(); //is 0
int count = DescribePixelFormat(device_context, 1, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), NULL);
DWORD error_after = GetLastError(); //is 1150
```

The problem only occurs in Release x64 mode, and the same code worked fine with VS 2010.  Could this have something to do with VS 2013 thinking it needs Win 8 or something?  What's going on here?

Comment: Sounds like a classic mistake, calling GetLastError() when you have not in fact got a failure return code from a winapi function.  That's wrong, Windows does not go to through the trouble of resetting the error code when there is no error.  Of course, nobody can see your code to see if that is the case, forcing us to guess is not productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that calls `GetLastError` is incorrect. The documentation of [`DescribePixelFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318302.aspx) says:

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the maximum pixel format
>   index of the device context. In addition, the function sets the
>   members of the `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` structure pointed to by ppfd
>   according to the specified pixel format.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information, call `GetLastError`.

In other words, you need to check the return value of the `DescribePixelFormat` function. You are not doing that. Only in the case where `DescribePixelFormat` returns zero does the value returned by `GetLastError` have any meaning.

Comment: I was confused by this, since I had assumed GetLastError would return 0 if there weren't any error.  Reading GetLastError's documentation also gives "Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed."